# Are wizards with the Improved Familiar Attunement and the Enhanced Familiar feat restricted to only picking familiar abilities?

Tags: feats, class-feature, wizard, familiars, pathfinder-2e

From PF2E Core Rulebook p. 218:

> Familiar and Master Abilities
>
> Each day, you channel your magic into two abilities, which can be either familiar or master abilities....

Which is fine and makes sense. On p. 205:

> Improved Familiar Attunement
>
> ...Your familiar gains an extra ability, and it gains an additional extra ability when you reach 6th, 12th, and 18th levels.

And on p. 210:

> Enhanced Familiar
>
> You infuse your familiar with additional magical energy. You can select four familiar or master abilities each day, instead of two.
>
> **Special** If your arcane thesis is improved familiar attunement, your familiar's base number of familiar abilities, before adding any extra abilities from the arcane thesis, is four.

Does having all these features restrict me to picking only familiar abilities, and not master abilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can have both.

Improved Familiar adds 1-4 additional abilities that *must* be Familiar abilities (because there is no mention of Master abilities). This does not affect your base 2 Familiar/Master abilities.

> Your familiar **gains** an extra ability, and it **gains** an additional extra ability

Enhanced Familiar adds 2 additional abilities that can be either Familiar or Master abilities.

> You infuse your familiar with additional magical energy. **You can select four familiar or master abilities each day, instead of two.**
>
> **Special** If your arcane thesis is improved familiar attunement, your familiar's base number of familiar abilities [...] is four.

Total: 4 "flexible" abilities and 4 Familiar abilities

Comment: So there are 4 "flexible" abilities and 4 Familiar abilities at level 2, before adding additional (familiar) abilities from Improved Familiar Attunement?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.